# flutter bottom navigation and drawer

Tags: flutter

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
 }

 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 int _selectedIndex = 0;
 List<Widget>firstFlowpagesList=List();
 final bottomNavigationColor=const  Color(0xFF364195);

 @override
   void initState() {
     firstFlowpagesList
     ..add(HomeFragment())
     ..add(StylistPage())
     ..add(MyAppointmentsPage())
     ..add(HairtipsPage())
    ..add(AccountPage());
     super.initState();
   }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    //  appBar: AppBar(
    //    title: Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
    //  ),
    //  body: Center(
    //    child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),

    //  ),
     body: firstFlowpagesList[_selectedIndex],
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
       items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home,color:bottomNavigationColor), title: Text('Home',style: TextStyle(color:bottomNavigationColor))),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.business,color:bottomNavigationColor), title: Text('Business',style: TextStyle(color:bottomNavigationColor))),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school,color:bottomNavigationColor), title: Text('School',style: TextStyle(color:bottomNavigationColor))),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit,color:bottomNavigationColor),title: Text('Haitips',style: TextStyle(color:bottomNavigationColor))),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.access_time,color:bottomNavigationColor),title: Text('Account',style: TextStyle(color:bottomNavigationColor))),
       ],
       currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
       fixedColor:const Color(0xFF364195),
       onTap: _onItemTapped,
     ),
   );
   }
    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
   setState(() {
     _selectedIndex = index;
   });
 }

 }
```

Here is my code for bottom navigation i want to implement drawer and bottom navigation in my app.How to implement both in one app.I know how to implement i android but i don't know how to execute the same in flutter

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get what problem you are having in order to implement both, it should be simple.

```
Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(child: ListView(children: [...]), // You can use ListTile for children and handle onTap()
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(...),
)
```